# Using system functions directly using the Saxon API

Tags: saxon

I want to convert a user-provided JSON document to its XML representation using the Saxon API, which afterwards serves as the input to an XSLT transformation.

Is there a way I can do this conversion without actually using XQuery/XPath?

I have tried to use `JsonToXMLFn` to mimic the `json-to-xml` XPath function without actually writing XSLT or XQuery, but I quickly ran into issues because it (quite logically) needs an `XPathContext`, and I didn't find an easy way to generate that using the public API.

Currently I use

```java
XQueryExecutable exec = processor.newXQueryCompiler().compile("json-to-xml(.)");
XQueryEvaluator eval = exec.load();
eval.setContextItem(new XdmAtomicValue(jsonString));
XdmDestination destination = new XdmDestination();
eval.run(destination);
return destination.getXdmNode();
```

Which works fine. But I wonder if there is a way without needing to parse and compile the XQuery expression.

Comment: I guess using https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html#evaluateSingle-java.lang.String-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmItem- e.g. `processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluateSingle("json-to-xml(.)", new XdmAtomicValue(jsonString))` is a bit less code although still using the compiler to parse the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `XdmFunctionItem.getSystemFunction(processor, new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", "json-to-xml"), 1).call(processor, new XdmAtomicValue(jsonString))` could work but with HE 10.2 it throws an exception "Dynamic functions require Saxon-PE or higher".

I am not sure whether that is still intended given that in XPath expressions HE 10 allows dynamic function calls; the documentation https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmFunctionItem.java#L69 says:

> ```
>  * Get a system function. This can be any function defined in XPath 3.1 functions and operators,
>  * including functions in the math, map, and array namespaces. It can also be a Saxon extension
>  * function, provided a licensed Processor is used.
>  * @return the requested function, or null if there is no such function. Note that some functions
>  * (those with particular context dependencies) may be unsuitable for dynamic calling.
>  * @throws SaxonApiException if dynamic function calls are not permitted by this Saxon Configuration
> ```

and
https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/Configuration.java#L1505 just throws

```
/**
 * Get a system function. This can be any function defined in XPath 3.1 functions and operators,
 * including functions in the math, map, and array namespaces. It can also be a Saxon extension
 * function, provided a licensed Processor is used.
 *
 * @param name  the name of the required function
 * @param arity the arity of the required function
 * @return the requested function, or null if there is no such function. Note that some functions
 * (those with particular context dependencies) may be unsuitable for dynamic calling.
 * @throws XPathException if dynamic function calls are not permitted by this Saxon Configuration
 */
public Function getSystemFunction(StructuredQName name, int arity) throws XPathException {
    throw new XPathException("Dynamic functions require Saxon-PE or higher");
}
```

So it seems unless you use PE or EE this is not yet a supported option; with the patch https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/e5cb4f89b97633000285987b48638a53c6a81b51 or in future Saxon HE 10 or later releases it will work.

With the recent 10.3 release this now works:

```
    String jsonString = "{ \"number\" : 3.14, \"boolean\": true, \"string\": \"whatever\", \"data\" : [1, 2, 3, 4] }";
    
    XdmValue jsonXml = XdmFunctionItem.getSystemFunction(processor, new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", "json-to-xml"), 1).call(processor, new XdmAtomicValue(jsonString));
    
    System.out.println(jsonXml);
```

gives

```
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <number key="number">3.14</number>
   <boolean key="boolean">true</boolean>
   <string key="string">whatever</string>
   <array key="data">
      <number>1</number>
      <number>2</number>
      <number>3</number>
      <number>4</number>
   </array>
</map>
```

Comment: Indeed now that higher-order functions are implemented in Saxon-HE it should now be possible to support this API under Saxon-HE and I will add a ticket to do so.

Comment: Thanks for investigating, Martin. That seems indeed like it could do what I need. It would be nice to have an interface in Saxon that can directly deal with JSON input (this article: https://www.xml.com/articles/2017/02/14/why-you-should-be-using-xslt-30/ suggests that it's possible, but either that's wrong or it didn't make it into the final XSLT 3 spec?)

Comment: @wasmachien, I am not sure which part of the article you infer that from, you can write stylesheets processing e.g. `<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">` or `<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]">` and you can use XPath or XQuery against maps or arrays, that is part of the specs and part of Saxon. As far as I know, there is no other way than using `parse-json` or `json-doc` as XPath functions to construct such maps or arrays from JSON strings or URIs, not sure whether Saxonica is planning to a a JSonDocumentBuilder or similar.

Comment: @wasmachien, in the fiddle I have created with Saxon .NET for XQuery JSON can be processed, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbc/1 or https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMee/1. The input JSON string is parsed with `parse-json` and then used as the context item for XQuery.

Comment: The article uses `<xsl:variable name="employees-a" select="json-to-xml(/)"/>` - but I don't think that can ever work?

Comment: @wasmachien, in my understanding that would only work if you feed an XML document that has a string value that is JSON, e.g. a root element containing the JSON.

Comment: @wasmachien, Saxon 10.3 HE is now available where e.g. `XdmFunctionItem.getSystemFunction(processor, new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", "json-to-xml"), 1)` is supported.